Null space of restriction and diagonalizability
I was practising with exercises on Jordan canonical form in Section 7.1 of Friedberg et al. Linear Algebra, in the point f) of exercise 7 it's said to prove that given a diagonalizable linear operator $T$ on $V$ a vector space, suppose $W$ is a subspace such that $W$ is $T$-invariant, then the restriction $T_W : W \rightarrow W$ is diagonalizable, I've to prove this using the fact that a linear operator $$U : V \rightarrow V \qquad \text{is diagonalizable} \qquad \iff \qquad \operatorname{rank}(U-\lambda_iI_V) =\operatorname{rank}\left(\left(U-\lambda_i I_V \right)^2 \right) \,\, \forall i,$$ where the power of $2$ means that the operator is applied two times (e.g $U^2(x) = U \left(U(x\right))$). I tried to prove it, but I cannot understand a crucial passage: let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $T_W$, then it's an eigenvalue of $T$, so since $T$ is diagonalizable, I can write $$\operatorname{rank}(T-\lambda I_V) =\operatorname{rank}((T-\lambda I_V)^2) \implies N(T− \lambda I_V) = N \left(\left(T− \lambda I_V \right)^2 \right),$$ where $N$ represent the null space (for an operator $U$ it's the space of vector $x$ such that $U(x) = 0$); now this fact should directly entail that $N(T_W− \lambda I_W) = N \left(\left(T_W− \lambda I_W \right)^2 \right)$ but I don't understand why.

$T^{'}:= T- \lambda \cdot I$ and $T^{'}_{\vert W}:= T_{\vert W}- \lambda  \cdot I_{\vert W}$.  By diagonalizability of $T'$ you know $\ker T^{'} =\ker \big(T^{'}\big)^2 $.  Now use the fact that the intersection of 2 subspaces is a subspace and write the same thing two different ways.
$\ker T^{'}_{\vert W}= W \cap \ker T^{'} = W\cap \ker \big(T^{'}\big)^2 = \ker \big(T^{'}_{\vert W}\big)^2$
$\implies \text{rank }T^{'}_{\vert W}=\text{rank }\big(T^{'}_{\vert W}\big)^2$
i.e. $\lambda$ is semi-simple for $T_{\vert W}$
